# ¿Cómo usar import en JS?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, javascript-import

Estoy intentando usar la clausula **import** para usar el ***d3.js*** pero en la consola me dice que no puedo usar **import** fuera de un módulo.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Ahora cuando cambio el tipo de elemento en el `type` por `type="module"` me indica que no existe una *funcion select exportada en el d3.js*:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './d3.js' does not provide an export named 'select'

Estoy usando la siguiente sentencia en el JS de la aplicación:

```
//app.js
import { select } from './d3.js';
```

También la he estado usando de esta manera como indica el manual

```
//app.js
import { select } from 'd3';
```

Pero no funciona.

Gracias por su ayuda y direccionamiento en el tema. No sé cómo usar la sentencia o cláusula `import`.

Comment: podrias poner el codigo de d3.js? Se me hace que podes tener mal el export que va en este achivo. Al final del mismo deberia ir algo como ``export default d3;``

Comment: El d3.js es una libreria de un tercero, no es mia, es una libreria de https://d3js.org/ y se supone que esta bien construida, ahora en los tutoriales dicen que se debe usar la sentencia import como lo especifico arriba pero siempre sale el error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: Ahh bien, y probaste las variantes que muestra la documentación? como ``import * as d3 from "d3";``

Comment: El modulo "select" en la documentacion lo importa de otro lado. ``import {select, selectAll} from "d3-selection";``

Comment: Hola de nuevo, gracias por tus respuestas. Si claro ya he probado varias opciones, pero lo que estoy viendo es que no funciona el import... es decir, el error dice que no lo puedo usar así no mas, mi inquietud es si debo realizar algún tipo de configuración a través de otro archivo o algo asi. Ahora, cuando quito el import y uso d3.select, si funciona, el problema es que tengo otras tantas lineas en las que ya puedo usar esta regla. Y mi pregunta es por que en los tutoriales todo funciona perfecto usando import pero a mi no me sale. jejejeje. Gracias. Como podria usar ES6 dentro de JS estandar

Answer (score 0):

he revisado un poco el tema, pero sucede lo siguiente en los ejemplos que veo de d3, se incluye el script con el d3.js en html, a posterior solamente se accede desde js como d3.select() desde donde necesites utilizarlo ( te adjunto un link de uno de los ejemplos https://riptutorial.com/es/d3-js para que veas por ahi también te es de utilidad).

En cuanto al error que te tira el import con la linea `import { select } from './d3.js';` es una destructuracion, osea solo te tomara la funcion select de todo lo que exporte el archivo, y al darte ese error sucede porque en el archivo que estas accediendo no se realizo el `module.export = { select }`  para que puedas acceder de esa manera a la función.
No dispongo del archivo para comprobar esto, pero por lo que entiendo al incluir el script en html que te cargue el d3.js ya vas a tener acceso en todo el siguiente código con d3.select().

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

d3.select("body").append("span")
    .text("Hello, world!");

</script>
```

Ahora, tema a resolver, cuando queres importar el d3, bajaste sus archivos y los tenes en el directorio al que intentas acceder asumo, o estas trabajando en nodejs por ej e instalaste el paquete por npm. en el ejemplo que te paso lo carga directamente desde d3js.org. si tu caso es el segundo, recorda que en nodejs debes realizarlo asi:

```
var d3 = require("d3"),
    jsdom = require("jsdom");

var document = jsdom.jsdom(),
    svg = d3.select(document.body).append("svg");
```

Espero te sirva de algo lo que pude encontrar, sino comentame a ver si encontramos la respuesta correcta!

Answer (score -3):

en la siguiente pagina hay diferentes manera de emplear el metodo "import". Espero te sirva. Saludos.

```
import defaultExport from "module-name";
import * as name from "module-name";
import { export } from "module-name";
import { export as alias } from "module-name";
import { export1 , export2 } from "module-name";
import { export1 , export2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";
import defaultExport, { export [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";
import defaultExport, * as name from "module-name";
import "module-name";
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/import

Comment: OK, asi tal cual la estoy usando, pero el problema es que tengo un error en consola: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" y supongo que debe existir una manera de implementar la libreria de d3js.org .